# List with object and index filtering out the object depends upon the index present at list

Tags: java

I have a following list which indicates the indexes.

```
 List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 3, 5, 6); // index
```

I have the following collection of objects.

```
Collection<Test> testCollection = new ArrayList<>();

Test test01 = new Test(0, "A"); // 0
Test test02 = new Test(1, "B"); // 1
Test test03 = new Test(2, "C"); // 2
Test test04 = new Test(3, "D"); // 3
Test test05 = new Test(4, "E"); // 4
Test test06 = new Test(5, "F"); // 5

testCollection.add(test01);
testCollection.add(test02);
testCollection.add(test03);
testCollection.add(test04);
testCollection.add(test05);
testCollection.add(test06);
```

The `integerList` has indexes which are present on `testCollection`. I want to filter out the `testCollection` which will have object consisting the index `1, 3, 5`. Index `6` is not present on object collection.

I wrote the code as below example. Is there any better as like Java 8 way?

```
List<Test> testList = new ArrayList<>(testCollection);
List<Test> newTestList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Integer integer : integerList) {

  for (int j = 0; j < testList.size(); j++) {

    if (integer == j) {
      newTestList.add(testList.get(j));
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(newTestList);
```

It will have the following output as result:

```
[Test{id=1, name='B'}, Test{id=3, name='D'}, Test{id=5, name='F'}]
```

The class `Test` has following information.

```
class Test {
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

Comment: Both lists are sorted, is that guaranteed?

Comment: `integerList` will not be sorted but testCollection will at sorted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that your solution is basically O(n*m),the size of the unfiltered list times the number of filter indexes.  I think you can get O(n+mlogm),the size of the unfiltered list plus sorting the filtered indexes, by using a combination of indexes and iterators and iterating through both lists at the same time.  It could look something like this:

```
public static List<Test> getFilteredList(Collection<Test> unfilteredList, List<Integer> filterIndexes) {
    if(filterIndexes == null || filterIndexes.size() == 0){
        return new ArrayList<Test>(unfilteredList);
    }
    Collections.sort(filterIndexes);        
    List<Test> newTestList = new ArrayList<>();
    Iterator uIterator = unfilteredList.iterator();
    Iterator fIterator = filterIndexes.iterator();
    Integer fIndex = (Integer)fIterator.next();
    for (Integer uIndex = 0;uIterator.hasNext();++uIndex) {
        Test nextTest = (Test)uIterator.next();
        if (uIndex == fIndex) {
            newTestList.add(nextTest);
            if(!fIterator.hasNext()){
               break;
            }else{
                fIndex = (Integer)fIterator.next();
                if(fIndex >= unfilteredList.size()){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newTestList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter and map the `integerList` but not sure that it will be more efficient.

```
List<Test> result = integerList.stream()
            .filter(index -> index>-1 && index<testList.size())
            .map(testList::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```